# Cannot connect with docker MySQL server container with the host name specified in docker-compose file

Tags: docker

When I set hostname as `localhost` in `MySQL Work Bench`, It works. But when I use the hostname as `msqldb` it doesn't work and show that hostname `msqldb` cannot be resolved. What can be the issue?

Below is the `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: "3"
services:
    msqldb:
        image: mysql:8.0.20
        environment:
          MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: psd
          MYSQL_PASSWORD: psd
          MYSQL_DATABASE: restaurantratingsystem
        ports:
            - "3315:3306"

    dj:
        container_name: dj
        build: django
        command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:80
        volumes:
            - ./django:/code
        ports:
            - "80:80"
        depends_on:
          - msqldb
```

Comment: The host names work between the Docker containers, because the host name/container IPs have been mapped in the container hosts file. If you do this on your host machine too, then the host names will work outside of Docker.

Comment: The hostname should be same a docker container name because docker internal networking resolve IP addesses using container name

Comment: If the Workbench tool is running outside of Docker, it can't use the Docker-internal DNS names; it has to use the server's DNS name or IP address (or if it's running on the same host as the containers, `localhost`).

Comment: Set `hostname: msqldb` in services msqldb and run.

Comment: Thank you for everyone for helping me. Yah, my problem is forgetting where I'm actually working - inside Docker or outside Docker.